# Decoding Problems with Images from Microscope captured with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, camera, vlc

I am trying to capture images from an [EVOCAM II Microscope from Vision Engineering](http://www.visioneng.us/products/digital-inspection/evo-cam-ii) using OpenCV. It says in its manual that it can be plugged into a computer using a USB 3.0 cable and then used as a normal webcam.

I am therefore using this very simple snippet to capture images from the camera:

```py
import cv2
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = camera.read()
if ret:
   cv2.imwrite('./test.png', frame)
```

However, when I should get `1920px x 1080px` RGB pictures, I am getting  `640px x 480px` images with weird artifacts:

[image: 640px x 480px image with weird artifacts]

I tried to test the camera on other software like **VLC** or **AMCap** but I either get a `640px x 480px` black image or the software can't even start the capture.

I am wondering if this is a problem of encoding or could it be something about how the camera *declares* itself to the computer.

Can I solve this problem by modifying some parameters in OpenCV or is it something different?

Thanks a lot for your time,

**EDIT 1**:

Output of `opencv_version -v` in my conda environment:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.2 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Extra modules:
    Location (extra):            /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/opencv_contrib-3.4.2/modules
    Version control (extra):     unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2018-08-07T11:32:43Z
    Host:                        Linux 2.6.32-696.10.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64
    CMake:                       3.12.0
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/gmake
    Configuration:               Release

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
      requested:                 SSE3
    Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
      SSE4_1 (3 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1
      SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
      FP16 (1 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
      AVX (5 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
      AVX2 (9 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
      AVX512_SKX (1 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_SKX

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++11:                       YES
    C++ Compiler:                /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++  (ver 7.2.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++11 -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/include -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=${PREFIX}=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++11 -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/include -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=${PREFIX}=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fopenmp -g  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc
    C flags (Release):           -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/include -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=${PREFIX}=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -pipe -I/home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/include -fdebug-prefix-map=${SRC_DIR}=/usr/local/src/conda/${PKG_NAME}-${PKG_VERSION} -fdebug-prefix-map=${PREFIX}=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fopenmp -g  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-rpath,/home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib -L/home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib   
    Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-rpath,/home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib -L/home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib   
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 aruco bgsegm bioinspired calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dpm face features2d flann freetype fuzzy hdf hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc java java_bindings_generator line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python2 python3 python_bindings_generator reg rgbd saliency shape stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect xphoto
    Disabled:                    js world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev cvv matlab ovis sfm ts viz
    Applications:                apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
    JPEG:                        /home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib/libjpeg.so (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib/libpng.so (ver 1.6.34)
    TIFF:                        /home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.9)
    JPEG 2000:                   /home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib/libjasper.so (ver 2.0.14)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.18.100)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 58.12.100)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 56.14.100)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 5.1.100)
      avresample:                YES (ver 4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev.h linux/videodev2.h
    gPhoto2:                     NO

  Parallel framework:            OpenMP

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Intel IPP:                   2017.0.3 [2017.0.3]
           at:                   /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
    Intel IPP IW:                sources (2017.0.3)
              at:                /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippiw_lnx
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       YES (ver 3.3.3)
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    /home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter/lib/libprotobuf.so (3.5.1)

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/py2/bin/python (ver 2.7.15)
    Libraries:                   /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/py2/lib/libpython2.7m.so (ver 2.7.15)
    numpy:                       /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.3)
    packages path:               /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/py3/bin/python (ver 3.7)
    Libraries:                   /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/py3/lib/libpython3.7m.so (ver 3.7.0)
    numpy:                       /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.3)
    packages path:               /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages

  Python (for build):            /opt/conda/conda-bld/opencv-suite_1533641454250/work/py2/bin/python

  Java:                          
    ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.7.1)
    JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/java/include /usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux /usr/lib/jvm/java/include
    Java wrappers:               YES
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /home/lucas/anaconda3/envs/p35_gpu_jupyter
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What computer is it attached to? Mac, Linux, Raspbian, Windows? Have you tried acquiring to a memory stick? Did you attach the cable to the side or the back?

Comment: You should ask the technical support of Vision Engineering.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, the picture is coming from a linux computer (Ubuntu 18.04). Opencv was not able to initialize the camera on macOs. I can save pictures to a usb without any problem and I can display the video feed on a screen using the build-in HDMI cable. I attached the cable provided with the camera to the back.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I did ask the technical support of Vision Engineering but I didn't get back from them yet.

Comment: There should be an executable where you built OpenCV called `opencv_version` Try running that with `opencv_version -v` to see what video codecs you have installed.

Comment: @MarkSetchell just added the information you requested in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR The cable used was USB 2.0, replacing it by a USB 3.0 solved the capture problem on Windows.**

Yes, I know it sounds quite stupid but the reason why I was getting this strange image is that the USB cable was a 2.0 and not a 3.0. As the cable was already plugged in the camera I didn't bother verifying it but changing it to a 3.0 made it worked instantly on the camera Windows app. The company also confirmed that the EVO Cam II generates a signal using the **DirectShow format**.

However, when comparing the images that are saved on the USB drive by the camera and the one capture using the USB cable I realized that the quality is not similar. And especially in my case the quality of the images captured using the USB cable are not good enough. I will therefore not pursue in this direction anymore.

However, for those who would like to continue where I left it, here are some links the Vision Engineering support gave me to capture the images using OpenCV on Linux:

1. [Webcam DirectShow Properties Page in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418990/webcam-directshow-properties-page-in-python)
2. http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/

For the moment they don't have a straightforward solution for it.

Comment: Well done and thank you for sharing the solution back with the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

**Different kinds of USB transfer**

The page you referenced does not say that the device can be "plugged into a computer using a USB 3.0 cable and then used as a normal webcam". The page says only that it has a usb 3.0 interface. The only resource available from the page you referenced, is the brochure, where it does not say its plug-and-play either.

In the area of vision devices and imaging devices, a common interface on top of usb, is the ["usb vision" standard](https://www.pleora.com/about-us/standards-leadership/usb3-vision/). Vendors that make such devices provide specialized drivers, and commonly provide example code on how to interface with popular libraries, such as openCV. Using devices with this standard provides increased transfer rates, lower lag times, and lower cpu utilization compared to plug-and-play. Often, a plug-and-play driver is provided also, but you have no guarantee. If such a plug-and-play driver would be available in addition to usb vision, you would want to use the usb vision driver instead, as it would be superior most likely.

The fact that the vendor says nothing about what driver it is, makes me immediately suspicious. I would contact them before any purchase, and have them explain why this is not mentioned (or maybe its hidden somewhere on their web-page?)

On linux (in comments you say you run ubuntu 18.04), this plug-and-play functionality comes through video-for-linux "v4l". If you want to use your device as you have shown above, you need to make sure that the vendor supplies a v4l driver, that works for your version of Linux.

**Ubuntu version**

As of writing this (19 November 2018), Ubuntu 18.04 has not been around long enough to expect stability of un-common use-cases. If the vendor of this imaging device provides v4l interface drivers, there is a reasonable probability it is unstable. Try using Ubuntu 16 if that is possible. If you find it to work with Ubuntu 16, even though your drivers is supposed to work for ubuntu 18, make sure to inform the developers you have found a bug.

Comment: I contacted them and they answered me that  EVO Cam II generates a signal using the DirectShow format.

Comment: DirectShow is for windows. Ask them about the Linux drivers. Specifically, if it uses V4L. (unless you are on a windows system now, your original post said ubuntu)

Comment: @LucasVandroux, ask "is the camera complaint with v4l (video for linux) on my ubuntu X.X.X version laptop?"

Comment: if they say yes, then ask them for a gstreamer interface example. These come as "gst-launch" commands, that you can easily run from your command line... and should pop up video, or stills, in a stand-alone window. If that works, then continue from there... do nothing else until you have that on your machine.... thats my advice anyway

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice, as mentioned in my answer there are no Linux drivers for the camera, the solution they gave me is to try to use DirectShow on Linux directly. I tried quickly but didn't make it work and as the USB cable solution doesn't provide me with good enough images I will not try further. I am now working on a solution using the HDMI output of the camera directly.

Comment: DirectShow is for windows only, afaik